# $1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8$ and digits of special integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer and assume digits of $n, 2n, 3n$ are all permutation of one sequences of numbers (in base $10$). For instance, if $n=1402857$ then $2n=2805714, 3n= 4208571$.

In above condition, must the digits of $n$ contain $1,2,4,5,7,8$? Furthermore, can we classify such positive integers?

There is no counterexample less than $ 10^{10}$ by search using computer.

Edit: as @peter says in comment, such $n$ must be divided by $9$.

Comment: If you can do exact arithmetic on larger integers, try $kn$ for $n=0588235294117647$ and $0<k<17$

Comment: It should be $3n=4208571$. You might want to see [Cyclic Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicNumber.html).

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A023086 for integers where $n$ and $2n$ have the same digits.

Comment: This is of course related to $1/7 = 0.\overline{142857}$.

Comment: @PM2Ring In this case, n still contains 1,2,4,5,7,8

Comment: @mathlove but there are still differences, by the way I have not found a counterexample by looking at cyclic number

Comment: @MichaelLugo Thanks, but still there is no counterexample in the list.

Comment: According to [this blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/06/11/when-do-n-and-2n-have-the-same-decimal-digits/), if $n=4225561128$, then $2n=8451122256$, but $3n=12676683384$.

Comment: $mathlove No, this is not a counterexample as 3n has more digits than n

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang: I know. If it was a counterexample, I would have written it as answer. I showed it because $n$ and $2n$ have the same digits without having $7$ as the digit of $n$.

Comment: @mathlove, oh I understand what you mean, that is why I impose $3n$ on my question.

Comment: See [oeis.org/A023087](https://oeis.org/A023087) for integers where $n$ and $3n$ have the same digits.

Comment: @mathlove Yes, none of the condition can be removed.

Comment: No counter-example for $n\le 1.4\cdot 10^9$

Comment: A necessary condition for $n$ to fulfill the desired conditions is $9|n$

Comment: @Peter, this is rather simple: as $3|3n$ and the property of divisible by $3$ only depends on sum of digits, so $3|n$ then $9|3n$ so $9|n$

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang I never claimed that this is difficult to find out. It is only an information how the search can be accelerated. Maybe, some users join in the search.

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Everything has been said in the first comments : this is about cyclic numbers properties http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicNumber.html.

The 9|n has been mentioned. If you look at the sample numbers - 142857 (from the 1/7 cycle), 0588235294117647 (from the 1/17 cycle), 052631578947368421 (from the 1/19 cycle) or 0434782608695652173913 (from the 1/23 cycle), you will notice that the digits add up when you split the number in two parts:

142
857
999

05882352
94117647
99999999

052631578
947368421
999999999

04347826086
95652173913
99999999999

So, allowing the number to start "with a zero digit", we can see that any 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 digit may appear, and not only the 142857 from the 1/7 cycle.

Hope this helps!

Comment: WELCOME TO MSE!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a computer-aided proof that the digits of $n$ must contain $1,2,4,5,7,8.$ Similar arguments might lead to some kind of classification, but I have not focused on that.

For each decimal position $k$ an important property is: which of the intervals $[0,\tfrac 13],$ $[\tfrac13,\tfrac 12),$ $[\tfrac12,\tfrac 23),$ or $[\tfrac23,1)$ does $n10^{-k}$ modulo $1$ fall into? This determines how many carries are sent to that position in the calculation of $2n$ and $3n.$ For example in $142857,$ looking at $k=3,$ we find that $\tfrac {857}{1000}$ modulo $1$ lies in the interval $[\tfrac23,1),$ which implies that there is a carry-$1$ in the next position (the thousands position) in the calculation of $2n,$ and a carry-$2$ in the calculation of $3n.$

In each position $k,$ we have one of ten options for the digit $\lfloor n10^{-k}\rfloor$ modulo $10,$ and one of four possibilities for the interval that $n10^{-k}$ modulo $1$ lies in. This pair determines the interval that $n10^{-(k+1)}$ lies in, as well as the digit in position $k$ in $2n$ and $3n.$ Some necessary conditions are:

- The number of times each digit appears in $2n,$ minus the number of times each digit appears in $n,$ has total zero
- The number of times each digit appears in $3n,$ minus the number of times each digit appears in $n,$ has total zero
- The number of times each of the four interval appears as some $n10^{-k},$ minus the number of times each type of interval appears as some $n10^{-(k+1)},$ has total zero.

These are all linear conditions, and can be studied using software for manipulating rational convex cones. Each of the forty possible (digit,interval) pairs defines a vector $(x_0,\dots,x_{23})$ in $\mathbb Z^{24}$ by the following procedure starting from the zero vector:

- subtract one from $x_i$ if the pair uses digit $i$
- add one to $x_i$ if the pair would produce digit $i$ in $2n$
- subtract one from $x_{i+10}$ if the pair uses digit $i$
- add one to $x_{i+10}$ if the pair would produce digit $i$ in $3n$
- subtract one from $x_{i+20}$ if the pair uses the $i$'th interval (so $[0,\tfrac13)$ has $i=0$ and $[\tfrac23,1)$ has $i=3$)
- add one to $x_{i+20}$ if the pair results in "$n10^{-(k+1)}$" being in the $i$'th interval

The digit zero with interval $[0,\tfrac 1 3)$ will give the zero vector, as will the digit $9$ with interval $[\tfrac 23,1),$ but the other vectors will be non-zero.

For a valid $n,$ the sum over the vectors corresponding to the (digit,interval) pairs at each position will be zero. If my implementation is correct, the following sagemath Python code shows that if we omit one of the four vectors corresponding to a single digit from the set $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\},$ we get a set of vectors lying in a strictly convex cone. This means that a non-trivial sum of the vectors cannot add to zero, which means it cannot give an $n$ satisfying the conditions.

`from sage.all import Cone
def digit_necessity_check(test_digit):
    vecs=[]
    for d in range(10):
        if d == test_digit:
            continue
        for x_index in range(4):
            x = [0,2,3,4][x_index]
            vec = [0,]*24
            t=6*d+x
            x2_index = [0,0,1,2,3,3][t//10]
            vec[ 0 + d]         -= 1
            vec[ 0 + (t//3)%10] += 1
            vec[10 + d]         -= 1
            vec[10 + (t//2)%10] += 1
            vec[20 + x_index]   -= 1
            vec[20 + x2_index]  += 1
            vecs.append(vec)
    return Cone(vecs).is_strictly_convex()
for d in range(10):
    print d,digit_necessity_check(d)`

Output:

`0 False
1 True
2 True
3 False
4 True
5 True
6 False
7 True
8 True
9 False`

---

In the Python code, I have encoded the interval as its lower boundary multiplied by $6,$ so $\{0,2,3,4\}$ (this is converted to $\{0,1,2,3\}$ for indexing into the vector for the cone). To get the $2n$ digit look up the (digit,interval) pair in this table:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{$\times 2$ digit} & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5\\
3 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7\\
4 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9\\
5 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
6 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3\\
7 & 4 & 4 & 5 & 5\\
8 & 6 & 6 & 7 & 7\\
9 & 8 & 8 & 9 & 9\\
\end{array}$$
The general formula is $\lfloor (6d+x)/3\rfloor$ mod $10$ where $d\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and $x\in\{0,2,3,4\}.$ For the $3n$ digit:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{$\times 3$ digit} & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2\\
1 & 3 & 4 & 4 & 5\\
2 & 6 & 7 & 7 & 8\\
3 & 9 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
4 & 2 & 3 & 3 & 4\\
5 & 5 & 6 & 6 & 7\\
6 & 8 & 9 & 9 & 0\\
7 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3\\
8 & 4 & 5 & 5 & 6\\
9 & 7 & 8 & 8 & 9\\
\end{array}$$
The general formula is $\lfloor (6d+x)/2\rfloor$ mod $10$ where $d\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and $x\in\{0,2,3,4\}.$ To get the next interval i.e. the interval that $n10^{-(k+1)}$ mod $1$ lies in, given the $k$'th digit (where $k=0$ means the unit digit) and the interval that $n10^{-k}$ mod $1$ lies in:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{next interval} & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
4 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2\\
5 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 3\\
6 & 3 & 3 & 3 & 4\\
7 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
8 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\\
9 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4
\end{array}$$

The general formula is $\lfloor(6d+x)/10\rfloor$ where $d\in\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ and $x\in\{0,2,3,4\},$ then round down the result to $\{0,2,3,4\}.$

Comment: Thank you! But what if there are many carry-$1$s in the several positions that are near?  For instance, $n=334$ or $n=333$ shows that you cannot decide the hundred digit by just looking at the hundred and the ten digits.

Comment: I suspect the determination in "In each position $k$, …… This pair determines the interval that lies ……." .

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang: your example shows why there is a difference between $n10^{-k}\in[0,\tfrac 13)$ mod $1$ and $n10^{-k}\in [\tfrac 13,\tfrac 12)$ mod $1$ - the number of carries when multiplying by $3$ is $0$ if the fractional part of $n10^{-k}$ is less than $1/3;$ the number of carries is $1$ if this fractional part is in $[\tfrac13,\tfrac23),$ and the number of carries is $2$ if it is in $[\tfrac23,1).$ This is why I am considering "(digit,interval)" pairs rather than just digits.

Comment: Oh, I understand this. But I am not able to check your code as I am not familiar with python, can you make your answer easier to understand?

Comment: @ZhiyuZhang: I've added some information for how the (digit,interval) pair determines the $2n$ digit, $3n$ digit, and next interval. I already gave some description of how this data is used to construct a set of vectors, that can be used to check if a digit is necessary. I think it should be possible to understand basically what the code is doing: all the indexing arithmetic is done on non-negative integers, the // means divide and round down to an integer, and the % means modulo with least non-negative residue (when applied to non-negative integers as in this case).